# Nest.JS CQRS: Is there way to make Command Bus and Queue Is external by using Kafka or RabbitMQ under the hood? Thanks

Tags: apache-kafka, domain-driven-design, cqrs, nestjs

I am trying to use https://github.com/nestjs/cqrs Nest.JS module. Seems there is impossible to make CommandBus and QueryBus implementations external like using Kafka or RabbitMQ under the hood and share command handling between many microservices. Am I wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Kafka support was added in 6.7.0

https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/2361

As documented, the command bus is observable, so you could consume the events and forward them into a Kafka producer or consumer, as you need to

Comment: Also issue here https://github.com/kamilmysliwiec/nest-cqrs-example/issues/8